# Why do rails form helpers change the id/name I provide, and how can I make it stop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

At it's most basic, I am try to add a text_field to a page.

`<%= text_field "specs[#{spec.id}]", :height, value: spec.height %>`

Alone, this works as expected when the id is `nil`. It generates

`<input type="text" name="specimens[][height]" id="specimens__height">`

which is exactly what I want and need.

Unfortunately, if I've already added the same element to the page before, it gives me crazy stuff.

`<input type="text" name="specimens[0/1/2][height]" id="specimens__height">`

Checking the element I'm comparing against, the id is still `nil`. Nothing has changed. There seems to be some sort of rails magic that is going out and replacing the value I'm trying to provide. It seems that it replaces the empty array with a slash-delimited list of previous values it has had in previous uses of the helper? But I don't know why that would be the case.

Why is it happening, and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

You need the `text_field_tag`

```
<%= text_field_tag "specs[#{spec.id}]", spec.height, placeholder: 'Enter' %>
```

Comment: data_select also does this - but there's no _tag version of date_select, is there?

Comment: no but you can view this `<%= select_date(:date_attribute, prompt: {day: 'Choose day', month: 'Choose month', year: 'Choose year'}) %>`